# Angular: Getting TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-install

I have an angular project as a private repository in my GitHub and after clone it to my device and run `npm install` to generate node_module from my package.json I get this error in my inspect window:

[image]

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "4.3.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --hmr",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.3",
...
      },
....
    }
```

Comment: Please share the github url

Comment: The issue is related to report-detail-dialog component, would need to see the code for that atleast.

Answer (score 0):

You Are using Every dependancy of 7.1.3 But your @angular/flex-layout id 8.0
So You need to downgrade that version or else upgrade other versions to 8

npm i @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24
Hope it will help you!

Comment: Did you Uninstalled that previous version..Then installed the new one?

Comment: Uninstall first the previous version then install